# jquery animate makes other elemtents dance

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

so I have this problem with jQuery `.animate()` function where I animate one element and it displaces all other elements associated with it.

This is the menu I am working with:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
    <div class="col-md-9 navbar">
        <ul>
            <li id="home_button" class="menu_button">
                <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
                <p>Home</p>
            </li>
            <li id="projects_button" class="menu_button">
                <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
                <p>Projects</p>
            </li>
            <li id="about_button" class="menu_button">
                <i class="fa fa-balance-scale"></i>
                <p>About</p>
            </li>
            <li id="contact_button" class="menu_button">
                <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                <p>Contact</p>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

To see what I mean, I transferred my code into [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kjgjdxmp/1/)

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal HTML behaviour. Browsers "flow" the layouts, so if you make one element bigger, it reflows the rest of the document and displaces elements where it needs to.

If you want an element to move from one position to another, you have to take it out of the normal layout. You can do this by setting the `position` CSS attribute of the element to something other than `relative`. For example `position: absolute` makes the element positioned relative to the whole document, `position: fixed` makes the element positioned relative to the window's border, etc.

Additionally, you can use CSS transforms which also don't affect layout. These allow you to do a combination of translation, rotation and scaling to an element without displacing it's nearby siblings. This is ideal for, say, a slight size increase on mouse over or to transition items in from off screen.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions

Either way, I strongly recommend using CSS animations and transitions, rather than jQuery animate. You can then use jQuery to apply classes to enable and disable animations.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes

```js
$('.animation-test').on('click', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('animation-test--enabled');
});
```

```css
* {
  font-family: arial, helvetica, san-serif;
}

.transition-test {
  padding: 20px;
  background: cornflowerblue;
  
  transition: transform 200ms ease-in-out;
}

.transition-test:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.animation-test {
  padding: 20px;
  background: salmon;
}

.animation-test--enabled {
  animation: identifier 1s infinite;
}

@keyframes identifier {
  0%   { transform: translateX(0); }
  33%  { transform: translateX(20px); }
  66%  { transform: translateX(-20px); }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="transition-test">Hover over me to see a transition on a transform scale (no Javascript required)</div>

<br/>

<div class="animation-test">Click me to toggle an animation (Javscript applies and removes the class)</div>
```

Comment: By the way, would you know how I could make it that inside each button would be a paragraph? like in the first one it would say Home, second one would say Projects but the text would reveal with the button, I have no idea

Comment: That is out of scope for this question. Ask another question.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to this breaking your layout, you'd also have to consider a way to stop and reverse the animation midway or else it'll keep going and potentially repeat if the user comes back to it. Try moving your mouse back and forth across all the buttons really fast on your fiddle to see what I mean. It's entertaining, but not the effect you want I think.

Fortunately not everything needs to be solved with javascript. CSS transitions are easy to understand and do all the hard work for you. Combine it with psuedo selectors and you'll get the effect your looking for.

CSS Transitions:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions

Psuedo Classes:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes

```
.menu_button{
  transition: .250s width;
}
.menu_button:hover{
  width : 100px;
}
```

```css
.menu_button{
  transition: .250s width;
}
.menu_button:hover{
  width : 100px;
}





/** Note so important **/
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.container-fluid {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.photo-placeholder {
  height: 350px;
  background-color: green;
}


/* Navbar menu */

.menu_button {
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

#home_button {
  background-color: red;
}

#home_button i {
  margin-left: 0.6em;
  margin-top: 0.5em;
}

#projects_button {
  background-color: blue;
}

#projects_button i {
  margin-top: 0.5em;
  margin-left: 0.6em;
}

#about_button {
  background-color: yellow;
}

#about_button i {
  margin-top: 0.55em;
  margin-left: 0.55em;
}

#contact_button {
  background-color: green;
}

#contact_button i {
  margin-top: 0.5em;
  margin-left: 0.75em;
}

stretch {
  width: 80px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3"></div>
      <div class="col-md-9 navbar">
        <ul>
          <li id="home_button" class="menu_button">
            <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
            <p>Home</p>
          </li>
          <li id="projects_button" class="menu_button">
            <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
            <p>Projects</p>
          </li>
          <li id="about_button" class="menu_button">
            <i class="fa fa-balance-scale"></i>
            <p>About</p>
          </li>
          <li id="contact_button" class="menu_button">
            <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
            <p>Contact</p>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>
```